# CSS/html center text next to floated number

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a list of items with a number and text stacked ontop of each other - I am struggling with trying to vertically align the text next to the number it is sitting along side. I have the number and text just floated left inside a div - possibly I need to take a different approach? See working exmaple here - https://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/gRpxrQ?editors=1100

My html for the items is structured like so :

```
  <div class="featured-posts wrapper">
  <div class="featured-posts--posts row">
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">1</span><a href="/blog/1">10 Tips to Avoid Dry Flaky Winter Skin, Safely</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">2</span><a href="/blog/2">10 Ways to Spa at Home</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">3</span><a href="/blog/3">13 Healthy Ways Winterize Your Routine</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">4</span><a href="/blog/4">18 Things to Love About Our Follain Soap</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">5</span><a href="/blog/5">&lt;3 at First Site</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS (SCSS) looks like so :

```
.featured-posts {
   counter-reset: section;

   .featured-posts--posts {
     .featured-post {
       margin-bottom: 40px;
       width: 100%;

       .featured-post--wrapper {
         margin: 0 auto;
       }

       .featured-post--count {
         width: 45px;
         float: left;
         color: red;
         height: 100%;
         display: block;
          font-size: 30px;
       }

       .featured-post--body {
         width: 350px;
         max-width: 100%;
         margin: 0 auto;
         color: black;

         a {
           cursor: pointer;
           text-decoration: none;
           color: black;
           transition: color 0.2s ease-in;


           &:hover {
             color: red;
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I am trying to have so no matter what length the text is - it is vertically aligned against the "Count" (the left number). Any input would be welcome! Thanks.

Comment: do not use float when vertical-align is to be achieve. Use display(table/table-cell, flex, grid or inline-block + white-space for old browsers https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZOJrv?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the parent

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.featured-posts {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post .featured-post--wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post .featured-post--count {
  width: 45px;
  color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post .featured-post--body {
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post .featured-post--body a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.featured-posts .featured-posts--posts .featured-post .featured-post--body a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-posts wrapper">
  <div class="featured-posts--posts row">
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">1</span><a href="/blog/1">10 Tips to Avoid Dry Flaky Winter Skin, Safely</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">2</span><a href="/blog/2">10 Ways to Spa at Home</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">3</span><a href="/blog/3">13 Healthy Ways Winterize Your Routine</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">4</span><a href="/blog/4">18 Things to Love About Our Follain Soap</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-post col-12">
      <div class="featured-post--wrapper">
        <div class="featured-post--body"><span class="featured-post--count">5</span><a href="/blog/5">&lt;3 at First Site</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```